# Rails routing problem, resources, resource ,or get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

With the following routes:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :newsitems
  resource :weather
  get 'weather'
end
```

I don't have a named route for the `get` action on weather:

```
   location_weather POST   /locations/:location_id/weather(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"weathers"}
 new_location_weather GET    /locations/:location_id/weather/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"weathers"}
edit_location_weather GET    /locations/:location_id/weather/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"weathers"}
                      GET    /locations/:location_id/weather(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"weathers"}
                      PUT    /locations/:location_id/weather(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"weathers"}
                      DELETE /locations/:location_id/weather(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"weathers"}
```

What do I have wrong here? I put the weather in there as both `get` and `resource`, but I really want to just have it as an action on my `locations` controller, as its not actually a separate resource. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If weather truly is not a separate resource then you might not want to use it in the URL and just call locations/:id to retrieve the weather for that location. However, if you are doing other things with locations - as I suspect you are - you should probably go ahead and create a resource for weather. It doesn't need to have anything in it other than the show method, but it's good to have just for inventory purposes and to be RESTful.

Try the following. I think it will provide you what you are looking for:

```
resources :locations do
  matches "weather" => "weather#show"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the 'resource :weather' and you'll get your location_weather route. If all it is is a custom action on the Locations controller that will handle it.